# How to fix this error "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'" is keep running and not ending

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator

When I click on debug/run "running Gradle task 'asembleDebug'" Start running but it keep running and never ends. I had tried everything but none of them worked for me. If you know the solution please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice is to cancel the debug session and try again. For me that works usually.

Comment: I have tried this many times but nothing changed